# Why am I not seeing data for my visualforce page which uses a standard controller

Tags: visualforce

The following code doesn't show any data.

We have an account object which a community_plan__c object has a lookup field to and third level where a Community_Plan_Goal_Setting__c object has a look up to the community_plan__c object.

The following vf page doesn't show data when I append a ?community_plan__c id or a Community_Plan_Goal_Setting__c id to the url. Why?

```
<apex:page standardController="Community_Plan_Goal_Setting__c">
   <apex:pageBlock title="Hello {!$User.FirstName}!">
      You are viewing the {!Community_Plan_Goal_Setting__c.Community_Plan__r.Federation__c } Goal Setting.
   </apex:pageBlock>
   <apex:pageBlock title="Goals">
      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Community_Plan_Goal_Setting__c.year__c}" var="yr">
         <apex:column value="{!Community_Plan_Goal_Setting__c.Name}"/>
         <apex:column value="{!Community_Plan_Goal_Setting__c.Community_Plan__c}"/>
         <apex:column value="{!Community_Plan_Goal_Setting__c.Goal_Amount__c}"/>
      </apex:pageBlockTable>
   </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: are you passing Id in parameter? second it will not display parent field using this way. And why you are using PBT remove that use apex:input or outputfield.

Comment: I edited the question. Yes I am passing an id parameter

Comment: pass community_plan__c  and use relatedList tag to display all child records.

Comment: Good idea but I need to show records in a table and that the current year fields as editable and allow the user to add records if they want and for previous year records I need to show as read-only. How to do this?

Comment: then I think you should go with Custom VF and Apex combination to handle all scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to show a table of all `Community_Plan_Goal_Setting__c` records, you could add a `recordSetVar` attribute (see the [apex:page documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_page.htm)) and get some kind of result (but would also need to add pagination logic):

```
<apex:page standardController="Community_Plan_Goal_Setting__c" recordSetVar="plans">
   <apex:pageBlock title="Goals">
      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!plans}" var="p">
         <apex:column value="{!p.year__c}">
         <apex:column value="{!p.Name}"/>
         <apex:column value="{!p.Community_Plan__c}"/>
         <apex:column value="{!p.Goal_Amount__c}"/>
      </apex:pageBlockTable>
   </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

But given that you want to filter by a relationship, then as Tushar suggests you will need a small controller extension.

Comment: I get this error when I pasted in your code "Unsupported attribute value in <apex:pageBlock> in vf_CommunityPlanGoalPSetting at line 2 column 60"

Comment: @ApexN-u-b My bad - I've changed the code so should be better.